# How to return record by month for last six months?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display all articles for the last six month?

```
  $articles = Articles::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) ='.$month)->where('approved',1)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Please don't use raw variables in queries, use a parameterized version instead: `whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?', $month)`

Comment: Ok tnx :) do u know how can i return records for last six months?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
$articles=Article::where("created_at",">", Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->get();
```

You need to import the namespace to use Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```